# Signs From The universe In Hinduism?

Tags: life, omens

Do Hindu texts say there are always signs from the universe about good or evil, or bad/good omens ?

Searching on here and online there are some topics that indicate what is a good omen or a bad omen. Like if you see this kind of birds or cat walking this way on your path and things like that, very interesting.

But is it a general rule in Hinduism that these signs will *always* be there in life ?

Like when Duryodhan was born from Gandhari’s lump of stuff (she had boon from MahaDev to have 100 sons)

Anyway when Duryodhan came out of those incubator type things that Ved Vyaas had set up, there were huge storms and thunder and stuffs. Cause he was an evil dude.

I understand it won’t def be so large and obvious as that. It can be small and blink or miss it sort of sign, right ?

But is it accurate to say that according to Hindu texts, there are always signs showing us what is good and evil in life ?

Comment: The limited perspective of good and evil is not the correct way to study Mahābhārata. In Mahābhārata, everyone including Kr̥ṣṇa are shown to be flawed, it is a piece which shows the realism of the world. Good and bad don't exist in pure unalloyed states among people in societies, but they always exist alloyed. It is not limiting like Christianity showing absolute good or absolute bad. Even the Pāṇḍavas are flawed in character heavily, and they aren't some angels. And even Duryodhana is shown to have some admirable traits.

Comment: Duryodhana was highly diplomatic, clever, strategic and had a strong sense of friendship. Even though he committed some extremely horrific infamous deeds (which mustn't be accepted and condoned), still he wasn't some completely bad or evil person as such. He had mix of qualities just like any other character. That is shown strongly by the writer when he makes Duryodhana ascend to svarga. It is to show that the world isn't just good and bad. Much of what Duryodhana did except disrobing and some inhumane acts, are normal things which happen b/w competing princes even historically.

Comment: So, according to me, the writer didn't want to show anyone actually as evil or anyone as totally good at all. If he wanted to, he wouldn't have listed the underhanded tricks used by Kr̥ṣṇa in Gadā Parva in Duryodhana's dialogues. The writer could very well glorify Kr̥ṣṇa and not list the wrongs done in battle or justify the wrongs done by him and Pāṇḍavas. But he didn't do that. He showed the reality, even when he may have very well been a devotee of Kr̥ṣṇa. And that's what makes Mahābhārata an extremely beautiful and realistic epic compared to many contemporary fiction.

Comment: Duryodhana although might very well be considered in Purāṇic lit as some demon who reincarnated. But I don't subscribe to this interpretation. He was a product of his situations, environment, learning and karma (including that which he did in his life intentionally). And the same goes for every other character. People often put the blame on Duryodhana but forget that Duryodhana's character has been much of a result of Dhr̥tarāṣṭra's upbringing of him, which lead him being spoilt and of course Śakunī's involvement in his nurturing.

Comment: @Bingming I agree w/ what you’re saying here my friend. Duryodhan was affected by his dad & uncle from when he was born & those guys influenced him so much.  Of course is more complicated than how I wrote my question, of course. However. There are people in real life who are very evil, sociopath types, and like many others I’ve encountered them (long story, you won’t believe, I tell it one day hahaha:D ) And looking back now more dispassionately, I think there were signs that I missed, cause fate didn’t allow me to have any religious understanding then. But fate giving me this info now 

Comment: @Bingming Mahabharath is wonderful written & very complicated & that is great. No arguments w/ that, I will spend rest of my life studying these Hindu epics & Hindu texts cause I have such great respect for them. At every levels of understanding they are giving such huge amazing incredible lessons of life. However along with that, for those of us who apparently had so bad karma (raises hand embarrassed ) that we encountered & were affected by monster types & sociopaths, there could be signs given. So I think is worthwhile to understand those & am trying to now, hence posting this question 

Comment: @Bingming However also thank you for your detailed and informative comments anyways, on this epic that is so wonderful and I fully agree with how complicated and shades of grey is the writing. We can happily argue many sides and levels of interepretation of fantastic terrific Mahabharath till sun goes down some day for sure  In posting this question, I think I would just like to know if there are always signs of good and evil. I think there might be. Just wondering if there is some quote from Hindu texts that could verify if this is reality of living day to day life in society.

Comment: Yes, what happened with Draupadi and what Duryodhana, Duśāsana did to her is absolutely abhorrent and inappropriate. There is no doubt about that. The epic and its writer doesn't seem supportive of those actions quite clearly.
What Duryodhana did was terrible and what Pāṇḍavas was equally terrible. By not stopping and not protecting their wife, they were a part of the heinous act committed.

Comment: Only Kr̥ṣṇa tried to preserve her respect, rest all those were there, no one raised their voice, and so according to me along with Duryodhana and his brothers, everyone else including the great Bhīṣma had to bear the responsibility of the horrible act committed because none of them stopped it. Where was Arjuna's bravery and Bhīma's strength when their wife was dragged? They just stood and fumed inside but didn't even take a single action apart from Bhīma swearing sometimes, which wasn't of any use.

Comment: Deleted one of the more upsetting comments to not disturb anyone who might read this thread later. As usual, really appreciate the discourse on these fascinating topics of Hindu texts 